# Getting the run_id programmatically from an AzureML run

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

```python
run = Run.get_context()
run_id = run.run_id
```

pruduces the error

> AttributeError: '_SubmittedRun' object has no attribute 'run_id'

But [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.run(class)?view=azure-ml-py) seems to suggest that as the correct way to glean the run_id from experiment code.

How should I glean the run_id from AzureML SDK code? (N.B. I am using a library that hides the call to `submit` from me.)

Comment: Posted as an issue on github [here](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/865) too.

Answer (score 5):

From github [here](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/865#issuecomment-599626701) it is a documentation bug, the correct code is

```python
run = Run.get_context()
run_id = run.id
```